# Create new object of template type, with params

Tags: java

I'm writing some JSON parsing code in java, and I've got a couple methods where the only difference between them is whether they return `JSONObject` or `JSONArray`. I'm trying to go from this:

```
  private JSONArray getJsonArray(String path) throws IOException {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(path);
    httpget.setConfig(requestConfig);

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build()) {
      try (CloseableHttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(apiHost, httpget)) {
        return new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(result.getEntity().getContent()));
      }
    }
  }

  private JSONObject getJsonObject(String path) throws IOException {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(path);
    httpget.setConfig(requestConfig);

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build()) {
      try (CloseableHttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(apiHost, httpget)) {
        return new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(result.getEntity().getContent()));
      }
    }
  }
```

to this (not valid code):

```
  private <T> get(String path, Class<T> type) throws IOException {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(path);
    httpget.setConfig(requestConfig);

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build()) {
      try (CloseableHttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(apiHost, httpget)) {
        return new T(new JSONTokener(result.getEntity().getContent()));
      }
    }
  }
```

How do I properly initialize a new object of type T with parameters? Can I somehow limit the possible values of T to JSONObject / JSONArray? I know of `<T extends Something>` form, but those two seem to inherit straight from `Object` with no common interfaces :(

Comment: `org.json` (which I'm assuming is what you are using) does not support generic deserialization. Use something more sophisticated like Jackson or Gson.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't think this is a dupe of that question. The other question is basically "how to parse JSON", while this is "how to create an instance of a class corresponding to a generic parameter", which is basically independent of JSON entirely.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the code was provided only to better illustrate my point. tobias_k got the essence of my question right.

Comment: I see now. Re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reflection to get and invoke a matching constructor, if any, and raise an exception if no such constructor exists.

```
private <T> T get(String path, Class<T> type) throws IOException {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(path);
    httpget.setConfig(requestConfig);

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build()) {
        try (CloseableHttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(apiHost, httpget)) {
            Constructor<T> constructor = type.getConstructor(JSONTokener.class);
            return constructor.newInstance(new JSONTokener(result.getEntity().getContent()));
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Provided result class does not accept JSONTokener parameter.");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is sort of [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), i.e. you do not really limit the type to `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` but instead everything that provides the respective constructor is okay.

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I was looking for. And given that most of my programming experience is with duck-typed languages, I'm fine with this. My train of thought with limiting to `JSONObject`/`JSONArray` was to allow compiler to infer that T will always have the proper constructor, rather than limit how the function can get called.